# Session change in between Request and Process user authorization

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to implement a simple login page that redirects a user to an OAuth2.0 login server, and then back to a callback URL after they have successfully logged in.

However I keep on getting exception with error message:

> Unexpected OAuth authorization response received with callback and
>   client state that does not match an expected value.

From debugging I noticed that the session id from before calling "RequestUserAuthorization()" and after are different.

I read from some SO answers that I need to somehow prevent session changing, but not sure how to achieve that in this scenario.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

My distilled implementation is as follow:

```
private readonly WebServerClientCustomImpl _oauthClient = new WebServerClientCustomImpl();

public ActionResult Login()
        {    
            IAuthorizationState auth = null;

            auth = _oauthClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();

            if (auth == null)
            {
                _oauthClient.RequestUserAuthorization(returnTo: _redirectUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // Save authentication information into cookie.
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(auth.CreateAuthCookie());

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            ViewBag.Message = "Future login page...";
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: I would like to remind any other people who bumps into this problem, make sure when you are testing, do not mix localhost domain and your app URL domain... If you do that the callback from OAuth server will create a new Session.

Comment: what do you mean by do not mix localhost domain and your app URL domain?didn't get that part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have problem with SessionId changing it in most cases means that there is nothing in Session object for this user. Just add anything to session and SessionId should stay the same for the user:

```
Session["UserIsHere"] = true;
```

Comment: Session state is an ASP.NET feature, not a view specific feature. So whether it's web forms or MVC doesn't matter.

Comment: @AndrewArnott can WebServerClient's RequestUserAuthorization method cause the Controller to start a new session? Using the method mentioned above my Session ID stays the same until RequestUserAuthorization is hit. The previous Session ID is passed to auth server, but when returned to web client after sign in, the client's Session ID changes.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... should I add the session variable on the client's side? But, is this something caused by DotNetOpenAuth or is it a normal behavior of ASP.NET (i.e: changing the SessionId value and consequently causing that error)?

Comment: @Kassem - It is normal session state behavior (not related to auth). Empty session and corresponding ID (in cookie) is not persisted in any shape of form.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I see. I've just tried adding the session variable at the client's side. I'm managing the the whole authentication process inside an `HttpModule` in the `AuthenticateRequest` event. Apparently, the session state is not instantiated by ASP.NET until the `PostAcquireRequestState` event. So I'm guess that could be the root of my problem? But why does it work sometimes and sometimes it does not. I could not figure out a specific scenario where it fails...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message but different problem.

The url (origin and redirect) I did register in google oauth panel started with www.

Some users where going to the web without the www, and had the error message.

i.e.Google cpanel conf: http:// www.somesite.com, redirect to http:// www.somesite.com/oauth2

Some users going to http:// somesite.com.

Solution:
Restrict users to use only the www version or redirect the naked domain to www, so the authentication request comes always from the registered domain in Oauth panel.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is:
In the google cloud platform, the

```
redirect_url = "localhost:8080/oauth2callback/"
```

while you input a url like `127.0.0.1:8080/authorize/` to start authority.
there is a session with the domain of `127.0.0.1` without a session of localhost.

so, use `localhost:8080/authorize/`